# In the Unhuman series, do we ever find out what Hobbes is?

Tags: unhuman-series

In the [*Unhuman* series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/123261-unhuman), do we ever find out what Inspector Hobbes is?

I don't want to know *what* Inspector Hobbes is, I'm just wondering if we ever find out, or if it is a mystery till the end?

Comment: Hobbes is an unhuman but he's not a vampire or a ghoul or any of the other ghastly things that they investigate. He appears to simply be.

Comment: He is a real tiger